# Web API for vs 2010 installation & configuration

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I want to start learning Web API for that i need to set it up on my visual studio 2010.

In order to get started i looked at online tutorial regarding installation & configuration of web API on vs 2010 which some what confused me and decide ask expert advice on this.

I have couple of basic question regarding web API.

1. How can i install Web API on VS 2010?
2. What are the basic requirement for setting up Web API on VS 2010?
3. Can Web API's be used with asp.net web forms ( As i have been working on asp.net web form, i don't have experience in MVC)

I am sure answers to these few question may help other user who want to start using web API on VS 2010.

Any help in this regarding is highly appreciated

Answer (score 14):

Web API is in the ASP.NET MVC 4 project. You can install it in VS 2010:
http://robertbigec.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/developing-mvc-4-web-api-with-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: Can i used it with asp.net web-form also

Comment: Here is the nice review: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms

Comment: Been a while, but nothing seems to answer this: is bundling/minification an MVC4 thing or .NET 4.5 thing?

Comment: According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx) it requires .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 13):

**In Visual Studio 2010 to add a project of type ASP.NET MVC Web API** we can:

1 - Have .NET Framework 4 & ASP.NET MVC 4 installed.

2 - Add a new project and select MVC 4

( on this screen there is no Web API template which is where many users may expect to see it )

[image]

3 - Select the Web API Template

[image]

This was a great question that helped me; I hope this answer helps too.

Comment: ^1 for the explanation with images

Answer (score 4):

You have to downlaod and install SP1 for VS 2010 , then download the ASP.NET MVC 4 Project from Microsoft 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=30683
and install it. 
I would rather download VS 2013 , it has the Web Api (also Web Api 2)  as standard - no need to download anything else.