# Can we use angularjs with vs.net 2010?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio

I just not sure about the performance of web application using vs.net 2010 & angularjs because has no any post or ideas from someone. Please someone share experiences.

Comment: VS.Net is a IDE! It does not make any difference what IDE you use when it comes to performance. Are you talking about specific technologies like ASP.Net, ASP.Net MVC

Comment: The problem is vs.net 2010 has no webapi for developing with angular

Comment: Not true, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782088/web-api-for-vs-2010-installation-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the two.

Were you thinking Web API and/or MVC and/or SignalR what for your server API calls? (I assume that was implicit - actually haven't used Web API or SignalR on 2010.)

*My experience* has been that the bottleneck when using Angular is having >2-3k watches, some of which are "deep" causing the whole app to run run slow on the client - MS server technologies are fine.  (Of course you can structure your app so that it's really chatty and thus not be performant due to the way you used the underlying technologies but there's nothing wrong with .NET web technologies and AngularJS.)