# Use web api 2 in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

How can I use `web api 2` in Visual Studio 2010.

Is there any way I can use web api 2 in VS 2010?

Can somebody please help or guide?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include Framework version 4, you can follow these steps. In Visual Studio 2010 to add a project of type ASP.NET MVC Web API we can:

1 - Have .NET Framework 4 & ASP.NET MVC 4 installed.

2 - Add a new project and select MVC 4

( on this screen there is no Web API template which is where many users may expect to see it )

[image]

3 - Select the Web API Template

[image]

You can see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782088/web-api-for-vs-2010-installation-configuration)

But in your case, you need to install framework version 4.5. Each version of Visual Studio prior to Visual Studio 2010 is tied to a specific .NET framework. Visual Studio 2010 and beyond allow for targeting of prior framework versions but cannot be used for future releases. You must use Visual Studio 2012 in order to utilize .NET 4.5.

But one user has found a scenario where we can use framework version 4.5 in VS 2010, please see the answer of David Woodward [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390175/targeting-net-framework-4-5-via-visual-studio-2010). If you can install VS 2012, it will be much easier since you don't need to download and install anything else.